# Are there any fluorescent proteins capable of transforming 500-600 nm light to 400-500 or 600-700 nm?

Tags: photosynthesis

In order to improve photosynthesis, which doesn't use 500-600 nm light, I wonder if that light can be transformed into useful light?

The idea is to transfect photosynthesis organisms with the gene for that protein to improve growth.

Comment: Fluorescence always absorbs photons of higher energy and emits photons of lower energy so transforming light to 400-500 nm won't be possible.

Comment: @Cell Only in most cases: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fluorescence#:~:text=In%20most%20cases,%20emitted%20light%20has%20a%20longer%20wavelength